# How to detect overlapping HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to find easily elements in HTML page that are hidden by given element (div)?

I prefer jQuery if possible. Do you know such plugin or something?

I searched in jQuery API (http://api.jquery.com/), but didn't find something useful.

Comment: What do you mean by `hidden by given component`?

Comment: You mean elements with overlapping X/Y coordinates, but different Z-index?

Comment: @Barmar: exactly this ;-)

Comment: You might be able to use [elementFromPoint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint) but I think it only returns the topmost element, so you would have to remove the div in question first and then test.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One possible solution is **jQuery Collision** extension: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquerycollision/.

> JQuery extension to return the collisions between two selectors.
>   Handles padding, margin, borders, and can determine either overlap or
>   portion outside. Returns JQuery "overlap" objects. Requires:
>   jquery1.8.3+, examples also require: jqueryui1.9.2+

Comment: I'll give that a try, it looks fine, I'll let you know ;-)

Comment: That's perfect for what I need and easy to use. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for something for debugging purposes, but please let me know if I've missed the question!

Firefox has a pretty neat 3D view (info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/3D_view)) that lets you see (more or less) exactly how the objects are being stacked. If you've never looked at it before, it's at least cool enough to check out.

Comment: Wow! I owe you a beer (a good one, not a Coors light) for pointing that out. I've been using FireBug for so long that I completely overlook Firefox's native tools. Very nice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/eyxt2tt1/2/

Basically what it does is:

- calculating the dimensions of each DOM element, and comparing with user's mouse coordinate
- if the match return a list of DOM elements

---

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var hitElements = getHitElements(e);
    var output = $('#output');
    output.html('');
    for (var i = 0; i < hitElements.length; ++i) {
        output.html(output.html() + '<br />' + hitElements[i][0].tagName + ' ' + hitElements[i][0].id);

    };

});

var getHitElements = function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var hitElements = [];
    $(':visible').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).outerWidth());
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++');
        console.log('pageX: ' + x);
        console.log('pageY: ' + y);
        console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).offset());
        console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++');
        if (offset.left < x && (offset.left + $(this).outerWidth() > x) && (offset.top < y && (offset.top + $(this).outerHeight() > y))) {
            console.log('included: ', $(this).attr("id"));
            console.log('from 0p far x: ', $(this).attr("id"), offset.left + $(this).outerWidth());
            console.log('from 0p far y: ', $(this).attr("id"), offset.top + $(this).outerHeight());
            hitElements.push($(this));
        }
    });

    return hitElements;

}
```